# Websphere Business Process Manager Webservice retry behavior

Tags: websphere, websphere-process-server

I'm writing business processes in BPEL for Websphere BPM 8.0, using IBM Integration Designer. Some of our processes contain activities to invoke web services. I was troubleshooting a process the other day that was trying to invoke a web service on a server that was down. I noticed that, according to the log, BPM tried the web service call five times before finally returning a "connection timeout" fault to the business process.

I'm trying to understand this retry behavior. The business process doesn't contain an explicit loop to retry the web service invocation, and there's no business process property that I can see to specify retry behavior.

I tried googling and was led to some pages about general transaction rollback behavior. It's not clear to me that this transaction-related behavior, and I didn't see any setting like "try each transaction five times".

Are these web service retries just an example of transaction retries? Or is it separate? Could someone point me to specific documentation on this "try n times" behavior, or where I'd configure it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As soon as you work with IBM product you have a deal with WebSphere Application Server this means that most of you code is j2ee application.

5 times retry is standard behavior.

[IBM Doc.](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21458614)

[Technical explanation](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21294883)

[Developerworks](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/0801_smirnov/0801_smirnov.html)

Answer (score 1):

In the latest version of BPM and WebSphere ESB (v8 or later), the retry logic is manageable directly in the visual programming model.

So if you need a fine tuning of this behavior, I suggest you to introduce a mediation component that on the invoke callout exposes a lot of features:

[Service Invoke and Callout nodes > Retry](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/dmndhelp/v8r0mx/topic/com.ibm.wbpm.main.doc/topics/esbprog_retry.html)

Another benefit of this approach is that you can configure a different retry logic for each invoke. In other words, two different invokes could implement two different behavior, depending on the business logic and on the backend system expectations.